# Strange behavior: Exchange 2010, delegation, OWA, duplicate sent items

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, delegation

Please help me understand this strange (to me) behavior

## Goal

Allow delegated users to send-on-behalf-of other mailbox using OWA **and iOS/Android apps**.

Sent items should appear only **once** in the *delegated* mailbox (no sent item should be duplicated anywhere).

## Configuration

Delegate has `Full Access` + `Send On Behalf Of` permissions to delegated mailbox

---

### OWA Scenario 1

> Messages sent on behalf of this mailbox will appear in the Sent Items folder of the: **Sender mailbox**

Delegates can send email from delegated mailbox - sent items appear only **once** in the *delegated* mailbox.

This is great from a desired behavior standpoint, but the **Sender mailbox** setting *should* cause the sent item to appear in the *delegate's* mailbox right?

---

### OWA scenario 2,3

> Messages sent on behalf of this mailbox will appear in the Sent Items folder of the: **From mailbox**

or

> Messages sent on behalf of this mailbox will appear in the Sent Items folder of the: **Sender and From mailbox**

Delegates can send email from delegated mailbox - sent items appear **twice** in the *delegated* mailbox and not at all in the *delegate's* mailbox.  **Why??**

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands to see if the **Send On Behalf Of** permission was granted to the delegates successfully, and to trace the sent items which were sent from delegates:

**Send On Behalf To**:

```
Get-Mailbox -Identity "<Mailbox Name>" | fl GrantSendOnBehalfTo

Get-MailboxSentItemsConfiguration -Identity "<Mailbox Name>" | fl SendOnBehalfOfItemsCopiedTo
```

**[Message Tracking Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/bb124375(v=exchg.141))**:

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender <Delegate Email Address> -Recipients <Recipient Email Address> -MessageSubject <Subject> -Start <Start Date and Time> -End <End Date and Time> | ft TimeStamp, EventId, Source, Sender, Recipients, MessageSubject -AutoSize
```